# Basic Auth apache 2.2 bypass IP

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, http-basic-authentication, mod-authz-host

how can set the basic auth of apache 2.2 to bypass IP? I have follow this wiki http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/BypassAuthenticationOrAuthorizationRequirements , but ask always a password, also to IP listed:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mydir>
    AuthName "Private"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 111.111.111.111 222.222.222.222
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

I am under haproxy but i set the IP forward, i have set `LogFormat` in this way:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

access_log is:

```
111.111.111.111 - - [25/Oct/2016:12:35:41 +0200] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 401 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Iceweasel/38.7.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configuration is fine and is very standard. If you are using `haproxy` then the source IP address of *all* requests is the `haproxy` itself and it is this IP address that the `allow from` directive is checked against, not the contents of the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

There are several ways to *fix* this. With Apache v2.2 you can use a 3rd party module such as mod_custom_headers (http://support.en.ctx.org.cn/ctx109555.citrix sorry the original citrix page seems to have moved or been removed) or possibly `mod_rpaf` (I've not used it before and so can't be sure if it causes `allow from` to work correctly).

These modules modify the data Apache holds about the request so that the source IP becomes the value from a named header set by your proxy (such as `X-Forwarded-For`).

Alternatively you can upgrade to Apache v2.4 and use mod_remoteip, which does the same thing.

Note there is also an Apache configuration solution by which you set your own header on the `haproxy` (or you can use the `X-Forwarded-For` one if you trust it). Something like:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^111.111.111.111 access_granted_by_ip
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^222.222.222.222 access_granted_by_ip
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=access_granted_by_ip
```

But I'll admit it's a little clunky for multiple IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks work's perfectly! I use `SetEnvIf` into `VirtualHost` section...i have tested with an apache 2.4 docker container and works, now the problem is the 2.2 installation, thanks again!